# How to increase Node Drain Timeout for AKS node upgrade rollout

Tags: azure-aks, azure-cli

Problem:

- PDB with maxUnavailable of 1
- Pods have LONG grace period of 15 hours (technical requirement for the business case at hand handling stateful connections. Also induced by external dependency, so no way for me to change this)
- Node Drain timeout is only 1 hour?

During an upgrade, a pod that needs to be evicted off a node might take longer than the Node Drain timeout and yields the following error:

```
(UpgradeFailed) Drain of NODE_NAME did not complete pods [STS_NAME:POD_NAME]: Pod
 POD_NAME still in state Running on node NODE_NAME, pod termination grace period 15h0m0s was
 greater than remaining per node drain timeout. See http://aka.ms/aks/debugdrainfailures
Code: UpgradeFailed
```

After which the cluster is in failed state.

Due to the grace period of pods not being in my control, I would like to increase the node drain timeout to 31 hours, as there can be 2 of those long grace period pods on a single node. I haven't been able to find anything regarding the node drain timeout though.
I can't even figure out, if it's part of K8s, or AKS specifically.

How to increase the per node drain timeout, such that my long grace period pods don't interrupt my node upgrade operations?

EDIT:
In the [kubectl cli reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#drain), the drain command takes a timeout parameter. As I don't invoke the drain myself, I don't see how this helps me. It lead me to believe that, if anywhere, this needs to be dealt with on the AKS side of things.

Comment: I understand you want to start a node upgrade. Would it help to evict the pods before starting the upgrade instead of creating such a long node drain timeout. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/api-eviction/

Comment: @enceladus2022 Not really, because the node upgrade affects all nodes of the cluster, one after another. I cannot evict all pods from all nodes without causing a massive workload outage. I could evict one node prior, start node upgrade, wait for it to finish one node, fail the next, repeat. But that's very tedious and will require active supervision for days, given multiple clusters with many nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Drain timeout is configurable in the august api of aks. Documetnation still pending.

A link to the August API Update that provides *drainTimeoutInMinutes*:

[2023-08-02-preview](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/main/specification/containerservice/resource-manager/Microsoft.ContainerService/aks/preview/2023-08-02-preview/managedClusters.json)

Comment: Please add the link to the docs, once they are available :)

Comment: Thank you. Once I've tried this and it works I will accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the actual question, but a possible workaround:

1. Scale up to double the amount of nodes you need to run the workload
2. Manually evict first half of nodes that need upgrading
3. Start the upgrade
4. Upgrade fails somewhere in the second half
5. Manually evict second half of nodes
6. Start the upgrade
7. Upgrade completes
8. Scale down to required amount of nodes again

Disadvantages:

- Doubled infrastructure cost for the duration of the upgrades
- Lots of manual steps for upscaling, evicting, upgrading, evicting again, upgrading again, downscaling
- Might require additional quota requests to actually perform due to possible vCore quota limits
- Manual nature of this upgrade will prevent auto-upgrading the cluster successfully
- At least doubles the time for the entire operation, because the entire workload needs to be evicted completely twice, instead of just once

It's a terrible workaround, but a workaround.